# Subscribe to a stream and forward it in flutter dart

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I use `firestore` to subscribe on a stream like this:

```
db.collection(collection).snapshots().listen((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
  // something
});
```

The `listen` returns a `StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot>`

Now I want to write a method, that is subscribing to this stream so I can do something when I get new results. But the same method should return a stream of this data on its own. I tried this:

```
static Stream<QuerySnapshot> listenOnCollection(String collection) async* {
    db.collection(collection).snapshots().listen((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
      // do something and now forward incoming snapshot
      yield snapshot;
    });
  }
```

This won't work as `yield` is not even known in the inner context. How can I achieve this? Thanks alot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tested, working

```
static Stream<QuerySnapshot> listenOnCollection(String collection) async* {
    var stream = db.collection(collection).snapshots();
    await for(final snapshot in stream){
        yield snapshot;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can map and transform the stream then return it:

```
static Stream<QuerySnapshot> listenOnCollection(String collection){
  return db.collection(collection).snapshots().map((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
     // do something and now forward incoming snapshot
     return snapshot;
  });
}
```